# Speed up or replace for loop:Group reshape and row bind

Tags: r, for-loop, reshape, rbind, coding-efficiency

Good evening guys,I want to combine the same id  row into one row,with additional column,and here  is my part of data.

```
sample=structure(list(crsp_fundno = c(18021, 18021, 18021, 18021, 22436, 
                                      22436, 22436, 22436, 22436, 22436, 49805, 49805, 49805, 55603, 
                                      55603, 93362), seq = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
                                                             1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L), begdt = structure(c(13513, 14298, 15027, 
                                                                                                          16149, 12417, 13969, 14910, 14918, 15042, 15644, 14782, 14910, 
                                                                                                          15544, 15505, 15531, 17571), class = "Date"), enddt = structure(c(14297, 
                                                                                                                                                                            15026, 16148, 17621, 13968, 14909, 14917, 15041, 15643, 17621, 
                                                                                                                                                                            14909, 15543, 17621, 15530, 17621, 17621), class = "Date"), crsp_obj_cd = c("EDYG", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "EDYG", "EDYG", "EDYG", "EDYG", "EDYG", "EDYG", "EDYG", "EDYG", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "EDYG", "EF", "EF", "EF", "EDYB", "EDYB", "M"), lipper_class = c("MLGE", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "MCCE", "MCVE", "MLCE", "MLVE", "MLVE", "MLCE", "MLVE", "MLCE", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "MLVE", "IMLC", "IMLG", "IMLC", "MTAM", "MTAC", "MATJ"), lipper_obj_cd = c("G", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "IF", "IF", "IF", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "GI", "GI", "I"), lipper_asset_cd = c("EQ", "EQ", "EQ", "EQ", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "EQ", "EQ", "EQ", "EQ", "EQ", "EQ", "EQ", "EQ", "EQ", "EQ", "EQ", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "EQ")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

I tried to merge row which has the same ID in one row, and here is my code.

```
temp=list()
dn=unique(sample$crsp_fundno)
for(i in 1:length(dn) ){
  part=sample[which(sample$crsp_fundno %in% dn[i]),]
  part=reshape(part,idvar='crsp_fundno',timevar='seq',direction='wide')
  temp[[i]]=part
}

library(plyr)
sum=rbind.fill(temp[[1]],temp[[2]])

for (i in 3 :length(dn)){sum=rbind.fill(sum,temp[[i]])}
```

Code works ,but too low in my whole data(94000 obs almost take 2 hours).

I think I should not heavily rely on for loop in large data set.

May anyone know how can I improve the code or my logic ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Isn't this enough?: `sum <- reshape(sample,direction = "wide",idvar = "crsp_fundno",timevar = "seq")`. It gives the same result as you get for your `sum` at the end of your code!

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan oh.....interesting.So I use a too complicated method to do a simple thing，Thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome:). I will add this as an answer and ask you to accept and upvote.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, using `reshape` is correct, however, the implementation is not ideal. The function is already optimised to convert between `long` and `wide` formats without the need for any `for` loop.

You only need to call it once and save time:

```
library(reshape2)
sum <- reshape(sample,direction = "wide",idvar = "crsp_fundno",timevar = "seq")
```

As you correctly had a hunch, `reshape` is able to smoothly change between formats.

In your case you have:

1. `crsp_fundno` is a variable in `long` format that *identifies* multiple records from the same group
2. `seq` is the variable in `long` format that *differentiates* multiple records from the same group

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend `data.table` when it comes to speed and memory efficiency.

```
setDT(sample) # in place, no assignment needed
sum3 <- dcast(sample,
              crsp_fundno ~ seq,
              value.var = names(sample)[3:8])
```

Here is a comparison of the `OP`'s `for loop`, the `reshape` way suggested in one of the answers and the `data.table` way suggested in this post:

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
   for loop 23.735154 24.190626 25.948536 24.722330 26.176343 42.764253   100   c
    reshape  6.448800  6.742147  7.196820  6.850390  7.379401  9.932432   100  b 
 data.table  1.928812  2.143367  2.362979  2.255964  2.447935  5.847116   100 a
```